What is the procedure for obtaining Green's function in a spherical (or non-Cartesian) coordinate scheme?
With the assistance of those on this board and Haberman's Intro to PDEs, I've managed to use Green's Function to solve 2D PDEs in Cartesian coordinates, now I need to move to a transformed coordinate scheme in 3D. I have since (independently) educated myself on solving Laplace's equation using spherical harmonics where the solution is $u_{lm} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l \Big(A_{lm}r^l + B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}\Big)P_l^m(cos\theta)e^{im \phi}$
I have the following problem:
$$\nabla^2 u(r,\theta,\phi,r',\theta',\phi') = Q(r,\theta,\phi); \ \ \ \ 0<\theta<\pi, 0<\phi<2\pi, 0<r<\infty \\ \cases{u(a,\theta,\phi) = u(\theta,\phi) \\ u(r,\theta,0) = u(r,\theta,2\pi) \\ \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} u(r,\theta,\phi) = 0}$$
and from the 3rd BC, the eigenfunction for r would become $R(r) = B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}$
What I need to do now is find the solution to the inhomogeneous problem using Green's function: $G(r,\theta,\phi,r',\theta',\phi')$, however I don't know how the steps change at all when moving to a new coordinate scheme because this is beyond the scope of my Haberman textbook.

For $Y_{GS} = Y_{CF} + Y_{PI}$, I've already found $Y_{CF}$, or the complimentary function, by solving the Laplace's Equation for the inhomogeneous boundary condition. I deduced from the boundary condition that: $l=0,2$ and $m = 0,\pm 2$, and $B_{0,0} = \frac{1}{3}a^3, B_{0,2} =  -\frac{1}{3}a^5, B_{-2,2} = -2a^5, B{2,2} = -\frac{1}{12}a^5$. My guess is we would want to keep $B_{lm}$ general for now and they'll be what we evaluate when we plug in the general form into our PDE
The next step is to find the Green's function from the complimentary function: $Y_{CF} = \frac{B_{0,0}}{r}P_0 - \frac{B_{2,0}}{r^3}P_2 - \frac{B_{2,-2}}{r^3}P_2^{-2}e^{-2i\phi}-\frac{B_{2,2}}{r^3}P_2^2e^{2i\phi}$, in two pieces
Plugging in Green's function into the PDE
$$\nabla^2 G(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\delta(r-r')\delta(\theta-\theta')\delta(\phi-\phi'); \ \ \ \ 0<\theta<\pi, 0<\phi<2\pi, 0 < r <\infty \\ \cases{G(a,\theta,\phi,r',\theta',\phi') = G(\theta,\phi,\theta',\phi') \\ G(r,\theta,0,r',\theta',\phi') = G(r,\theta,2\pi,r',\theta',\phi') \\ lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}u(r,\theta,\phi,r',\theta',\phi') = 0}$$
Setting $G(r,\theta,\phi,r',\theta',\phi') = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m = -l}^l B_{lm}P_l^m (\cos\theta)e^{im\phi}$, and plugging this into our solution yields:
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(r^2\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\Big)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Big(\sin\theta \frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta}\Big) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin\theta^2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial\phi^2}= \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\delta(r-r')\delta(\theta-\theta')\delta(\phi-\phi')$$
This equation means that our PDE = 0 for $r,\theta,\text{ and }\phi > \text{ or } < \text{ their ' counterparts}$.
$$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r'}) = \cases{\frac{A}{r}P_0 - \frac{B}{r^3}P_2 - \frac{C}{r^3}P_2^{-2}e^{-2i\phi}-\frac{D}{r^3}P_2^2e^{2i\phi} \ \ \ \ \textbf{r}<\textbf{r'} \\ \frac{E}{r}P_0 - \frac{F}{r^3}P_2 - \frac{G}{r^3}P_2^{-2}e^{-2i\phi}-\frac{H}{r^3}P_2^2e^{2i\phi}  \ \ \ \ \textbf{r}>\textbf{r'}}$$
Can I plug in the boundary conditions and go from there?
